# How to pass data between Python and HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, cgi

I'm trying to get inputs from a HTML form, perform mathematical operations on those inputs in Python and then post the results back using HTML tags. The outcome will be the input form replaced by the returned result.

I'm a beginner so I'm not sure why my code isn't working as there are no errors. When I click submit, the page just shows a 505 page for python (which I believe is normal as .py is executable and not viewable by the browser).

**Python**

```
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

input1 = form.getvalue('input1')
input2  = form.getvalue('input2')

result = int(input1)+int(input2)
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print("<p> this is it " + result + "</p>")
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="calculate.py" method="post" id="singleSequence">
<h4 class="title text-center">Single Calculation</h4>
<h4>Step 1:</h4>
<p>Enter your numbers to add</p>
<p>Input 1 :</p> <input type="text" name="input1"/><br>
<p>Input 2 :</p> <input type="text" name="input2"/><br>    
<input type="submit" value="Send Request">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I've noticed is the line `print("<p> this is it " + result + "</p>")`. It raises `TypeError: Can't convert int to string implicitly`. Use `str(result)`

Comment: :(. Only other thing I see are prints. One with parentheses, one without. Maybe that's problem. One point to HTML: use `<input type="number">` which makes it much easier for mobiles. However, if prints aren't the error, I give it up... And make yourself sure you are sending valid integers when testing..